# How to make a JQL query for issues with multiple components

Tags: jira, jql

I'd like to query all issues in JIRA that are associated with more than 1 component. Is that feasible in JQL, and how?

Answer (score 2):

```
component in ("component 1", "component 2", "component 3") ORDER BY  updated DESC
```

Above solution helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a solution that was feasible in JQL. I also don't believe I have the ability to write JQL functions so I didn't get to explore that route.

I needed to be able to get a list of my tickets with multiple components. I did this by exporting my tickets to excel and then added a column which checked the cell in the same row in the Components column:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",", P5)), "Multi Components", "Single Component")
```

This checks the cell for the partial text `","`. If it has the comma, `Multi Components` is returned.

Comment: Dumping the query out to Jira was the easiest for me. Not ideal, but a simple column filter where there's a semicolon summarised the issues for me.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work:

components in (mycomponent1, "my component 2")

More help available at the Syntax Help icon on the advanced searching page

Comment: Nope, that will return all issues which have a component from the list. What I want is issues that have more than one component specified.

Comment: That's a good one. Something which works for me is following jql 

project = xxx and component="Data Provider Component and component = "Grid Configuration"

which results in a list of issues which have both components

I'm not sure this is an answer, because if you have a long list of components and you need to specify all permutations, you will get a huge jql

Comment: That's a good idea, but I have dozens of projects and hundreds of components, so that's not really feasible.

Comment: I guess you'll have to write a JQL function such that you can specify  issuekey in componentcount(2)  to get all issues which have 2 components or the one that you illustrated.  We did it before, its not that difficult to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
component in ("Component A") and component in ("Component B")
```

Comment: The question is about tickets that have more than 1 component, ANY component. It is not about tickets that have explicit A and B components.